# Connect App-Engine app to other Google Cloud Instances - VPN or similar needed? / DNS possible?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We plan to use Appengine for our Node.JS REST-API which will serve content for our customers. The data will come from a MOngoDB Cluster (or Replicaset), which will also be hosted on Google Cloud Services. Some of the contents might be cached using the Memcache of AppEngine.

Now my question. Is it neccessary to setup a kind of VLAN or similar, to connect to the DB server? How can we assure that the DB server is connected with a good bandwidth / latency to the AppEngine instances? Or is this no matter of concern at all?

Another question, does Google Cloud have a kind of internal DNS, which can be used? So for example that we have a domainname like "ourmongodb.internal" which can be used in connection string of our REST API? Or how is the most recent approach to connect to our DB server instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you use app engine flex you can setup your nodejs app engine server and the GCE VMs that run the mogoDB cluster in the same network and than connect them both in the internal IP space.